# Многоуровневые объекты и бд

Tags: php

ТЗ: написать удобную и правильную с точки зрения ООП структуру для работы с большими многоуровневыми объектами и бд.

В качестве объектов - недвижимость. Она делится на 3 типа жилая, новостройки и коммерческая. У всех трёх есть общие параметры (локация, площадь, цена...) и так же различия. Тут всё понятно: создаём абстрактный класс Realty и наследуем от него 2 вышеперечисленных типа Commercial, Residential и задаём каждому отдельные параметры. NewResidential наследуем от Residential, т.к. у него всё тоже самое + 2 параметра.

Сложность для меня состоит в следующем: некоторые параметры можно объединить в группы, например локация и представить их в виде вложенных классов. Это будет удобно для работы с ними. Но для работы с бд лучше иметь одномерный массив. В итоге, я вошел в ступор:

- либо писать кучу геттеров в 3х классах и подклассах чтобы формировать одномерный массив и кучу сеттеров чтобы обратно их запихивать (забыл сказать, у меня аллергия на публичные свойства, поэтому всё так усложняю).
- либо сделать все 3 класса одноуровневыми и в случае нужды создавать объекты локации, цены и площади... и т.д. Но лично я вижу жуткую нечитаемость здоровенных одномерных вардампов.

Хочу узнать как решают такие задачи профессионалы.

Comment: Опишите, что у вас в локации. Пока совершенно не понятно, зачем вам понадобились массивы

Comment: Ну вкладывайте объекты. Массивы зачем?

Comment: Опишите детально предметную область. Какие у вас объекты? Какие у этих объектов характеристики?

Comment: Примеры вложенных объектов : Локация = страна, регион, город, улица, дом... - будет иметь методы геокодирования, метод выдачи адреса в строку (для выгрузки в формате яндекс xml). Цена = общая цена, за кв. м. . Images = методы для работы с массивом фотографий: работа с размером, создание миниатюрок, наложение логотипа. Всё в таком духе...

Comment: Проблема в том, как такую неплоскую структуру распихивать в РСУБД? Смотрите ORM Doctrine. Или храните "все скопом" в одной колонке в виде JSON, последние версии MySQL позволяют искать в JSON, и даже строить индексы. Или пробуйте MongoDB, например. Я за последнее. Потому что РСУБД это параллельно и перпендикулярно. А Mongo позволяет хранить разветвленную структуру и schemaless

Comment: Почитал про MongoDB и понял что это лучший вариант, котороый подходит под мою задачу: позволяет производить поиск по бд, меньше мороки с объектами и действительно удобно. Спасибо за совет!